# How to fix x and y axes on xy plane in 3D

Tags: graphics3d

So I have a 3D graphics with axes and ticks, but sometimes when I rotate the grahics the axes change their location to different edges, and I want this to be static. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Use the option [`AxesEdge`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxesEdge.html):

The first example from [AxesEdge >> Applications](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxesEdge.html):

```
Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}, 
 AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}}, Mesh -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Use `AxesEdge -> {{1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, -1}}` to get

[image]

and `AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}}` to get

[image]

The first case above (where all three axes meet at a single point) can also be obtained using the option `AxesOrigin`:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, -1}, 
 Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]